Bluetooth LE device gets unpaired from Samsung Galaxy S21 phone
We have a Bluetooth LE setup with a medical watch which is paired to an Android phone using an authentication code. The setup works OK on most phones, but specifically on some Samsung Galaxy S21 models the device gets unpaired after using it for a few hours. Is this a known issue? We've tried to follow the HCI log file, and it seems that at some point the phone "forgets" the authentication code.
We expect the watch and device to stay paired until the user unpairs it manually.
The issue happens on 2 phones out of about 20 models we've tried so far, both phones are S21.
We've swapped watches with other test users for whom this doesn't happen. We gave the users having those phones alternate phones to verify it is not something environmental. It is not.
We followed the HCI log and just looks like that at some point in time the phone "forgets" the watch.

If you have evidence, isn't this a case you should discuss with Samsung support?

We're talking with them too.

We're still looking for the reason for this. When creating a bugreport via adb there is a file called: dumpstate-.txt . Before the unpairing happens I see this message: "[BLE_STACK] BLE Auth fail  Reason : 99". Does the code 99 sound familiar to anyone?

There's one thing you can try.
Go into Accounts and Backup on your S21.
Then go into Auto Sync Data and Switch it off.

Otherwise I don't think this is because of the auth code.
This most likely either has to do with the environment the mobile device is in, or because the Gatt Client doesn't receive a response from the Gatt Server within the expected timeframe after polling it.
Every bluetooth connection has a Gatt Client (Device connecting) & a Gatt Server (Device hosting the connection, in this case your medical watch device).
Most android phones have a polling mechanism which under the hood checks to see if the connection is still active or not, and if the Gatt server is reachable. It's a similar concept to a ping, except instead of TCP it's Bluetooth.
If the poll fails (because of an enviornmental issue, strong enough magnetic field causing interference, or heavy equipment), then that will cause a disconnection.

I don't see how that can be the case. Until we added the authentication PIN code a few weeks ago, reconnects worked fine. They still do in most cases. Only on those two phones, once they get unpaired, when the application tries to reconnect, the OS pops up the PIN code authentication dialog again.

I will try your suggestion with Auto sync data.
